How to show $(\ln \phi)' \le H(t)(1-\phi) \Rightarrow \phi\le 1$?
$\phi(t), H(t)$ is defined on $[0, \infty)$, and $H(t)>\delta>0, \phi(t)>0$. Besides, $\phi(t)$ satisfy
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&(\ln \phi(t))' \le H(t)(1-\phi(t))  \\
&\phi(1)\le 1  
\end{align}
\tag{1}
\right.
$$
Then, I guess $\phi(t)\le 1$ for all $t\ge 0$.
Why I guess it: Consider
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&\psi'\le 1-\psi \\
& \psi >0  \\
& \psi(1) \le 1
\end{align}
\tag{2}
\right.
$$
I solute
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
&F'=1-F  \\
&F>0    \\
&F(1) \le 1
&
\end{align}
\tag{3}
\right.
$$
to get $F \equiv1$. Since  $\psi \le F$, I have $\psi \le 1$.  But the way is not effective to deal (1).
I asked a similar question yesterday, but it was closed, probably because I was sloppy, so I rewrote it today. Please don't close it, because I find this question interesting.

Suppose your guess is not correct (and the solution is not a constant), then you can assume a time $t_0$ as the largest $t$ that $\phi(t) \ge 1$, then on $(t_0, 1)$ you can solve the inequality easily, and you will find $\phi(t_0) < 1$. Contradiction.

@Yimin  Sorry, I can't understand you. You assume $t_0$ is the largest $t$ such that $\phi(t)\ge 1$ and seem $t\le 1$. But if $\phi(1)=1$, then $t_0=1$. Therefore, $(t_0, 1)$ is empty.   Besides, even $(t_0, 1)$ is not empty, I don't know how to solve (1).   Could you talk it detail ? Thanks.

In fact, I feel (1) is hard to solve, since $H(t)$ may be complicated.

no, not solving the equation exactly, this one $$\phi'(t) \le \delta (1 -\phi(t))\phi(t)$$ if the interval $(t_0, 1)$ is not empty, you can solve this inequality on this interval. If the interval is empty, which means either $\phi(t)\ge 1$ for all $t$, either $\phi(t) < 1$ for all $t<1$. The 2nd one is what you need. For the first one, you can solve $$\phi'(t) \ge \delta (1 -\phi(t))\phi(t)$$ on the whole interval then, since there are no sign changes.

@Yimin  Thanks, let me try.
